# "Allerdings" and "zugeben"

Tags: difference, word-choice

What's the difference between *allerdings* and *zugeben*? *Allerdings* is a modal particle which means "I have to admit". Can it be replace with *zugeben*? For example,

> 1. Ich muß zugeben, daß du Recht hast.
> 2. Du hast allerdings Recht.

Comment: I think these sentences are similar in meaning, but not really exact enough to compare. The first one is "I must admit, you are right" while the second one is "You are certainly/admittedly right." Allerdings is, yes, a modal particle as well as in interjection; whereas, zugeben is a verb.

Comment: "Zugegebenermaßen hast du Recht."

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to compare verbs and adverbs. And "allerdings" does not mean what you wrote here. Neither is it a modal particle. It introduces a contradiction and is kind of like "aber" ... and it has other meanings, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Zugegeben* is something that you can do (a verb):

> Ich gebe zu, dass du Recht hast!
>   (I *admit*, you are right.)

*Allerdings* means something like that:

> You aren't right very often, but you are right this time!
>   (Du hast selten Recht, diesmal *allerdings* schon.)

Here **but** means *allerdings*!

Comment: Zugegeben, die Antwort ist richtig (wenngleich auch nicht ganz vollständig). Allerdings bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob "something like that" eine tolle Erklärung ist.

Comment: Naja man kann nicht immer 1 zu 1 übersetzen, also "so etwas in der art/wie" !